# Getting access to parent scope variables using ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am currently using ui router as below: -

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
    url: '/login'
    , resolve: loadSequence(
        'base')
    , templateUrl: 'app/shared/main/login-main.html'
    , controller: 'mainController'
    , abstract: true
})
    .state('login.signin', {
    url: '/signin'
    , resolve: loadSequence(
        'login-items'
        , 'spin'
        , 'ladda'
        , 'angular-ladda'
        , '_loginController'
        )
    , templateUrl: "app/components/login/login_login.html"
    , controller: 'loginController'
});
```

Now in loginController I want to be able to access a function in the mainController.

Is that possible with my current implementation:-

```
angular.module('app').controller('mainController', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.showWarning= function(){
      //show warning
  }
});

angular.module('app').controller('loginController', function($scope, $state) {
  // I want to access $scope.showWarninghere;
});
```

Comment: Yes, you should just be able to refer to `$scope.getData()` from the loginController, but really something called `getData()` should be in a service that you can just inject where needed.

Comment: I am currently getting TypeError: $scope.getData is not a function, concerning the service you are right, but the getData is just an example, sorry for the misnomer.

Comment: I think it depends on how your page is constructed. If the scopes are nested you could access it, but nesting the states doesn't force that.

Comment: Ok it works, but is this a good way of sharing scope like this, i mean performance wise

Answer (score 1):

Extract the `getData()` method out into a service and then you can inject it into both controllers:

```
angular.module('app').factory('dataService', function () {
    return {
        getData: function() { ... }
    }
});

angular.module('app').controller('mainController', function($scope, $state, dataService) {
  // You probably don't need to put this into your scope, but if you do:
  $scope.getData = dataService.getData.bind(dataService);
});

angular.module('app').controller('loginController', function($scope, $state, dataService) {
  dataService.getData(); 
});
```

It is useful to remember that scopes and controllers are created and destroyed as you navigate between states, so anything that actually wants to exist in more than one state really does want to be stored in a service.

Answer (score 1):

*As said by Duncan and Sanjay, it might indeed be a better idea to use a service to get the data, but I thought I'd answer the original question so you know :*

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#scope-inheritance-by-view-hierarchy-only), for [prototypal inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance) to be active the **views** must be nested, not only the states.

So in order for `loginController` to have access to the scope of `mainController`, the `login-main.html` template must use the `uiView` directive (e.g `<div ui-view></div>`) which will be the placeholder for the `login_login.html` template of the `login.signin` state.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `angular service` for this.

I found a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KzW2rAad6MWUGBRfzkcB?p=preview) code to resolve your problem